# Python SysLog Files Location

Tags: python, logging

Using https://docs.python.org/2/library/syslog.html I am writing logs

Example:

```
import syslog
syslog.openlog(logoption=syslog.LOG_PID, facility=syslog.LOG_MAIL)
syslog.syslog('E-mail processing initiated...')
```

So is their any pythonic way that I can get log filename for **syslog.LOG_MAIL** where is storing the logs?

For example the logs are stores at **/var/log/mail.log** so how do I get this location of filename **/var/log/mail.log** using python?

Comment: I suppose that `syslog` simply writes to `/dev/syslog`, and log entry is being handled by syslog daemon of choice (syslog-ng, rsyslog, journald). All of them have different logic how to redirect log entries

Comment: @myaut thanks for your reply it means we have to fix the log filenames mail_log ='/var/log/mail.log' right ?

Comment: The _syslog_ Module abstract the access to all the syslogs and goes directly to the Logging System. Therefore you don't have to take care where the Logs are actually are located. Do you really need this Path?

Comment: @s.meissner yes i need this path to gather the logs info without fixing the path (for multiple platforms such as macos and ubuntu etc.)